# How can I extract a sentence containing a keyword from a block of text

Tags: python, regex, file, text

I am aiming to come up with a script that will search a folder of log files for a specific keyword, and output to a results.txt file the name of the file, the line number in each file which contains the keyword, the index where the keyword starts and the full line of text containing the keyword.

I have created some code which does this, but it has issues with examples such as:

> Hi everyone, we've planned some overnight maintenance this weekend  so that means you will not be able to use any device on the network between 7pm and 10am on this coming Friday evening/ Saturday morning (23/06/23 to 24/06/23). We apologise for the inconvenience this will cause but it is unavoidable. Please ensure you have logged out of the network by 6.30pm on Friday evening (23/06/23).

It correctly identities the keyword "device" as line 1 and starting at character 114 and quite rightly shows the whole block of text as containing the keyword "device" whereas I want it to display just the sentence in which it occurs.

I was thinking about either:

- for every "device", find the text after the previous full stop, and before the next one, or
- get n characters before and after "device"

Here is the code I've written so far:

```
#Import os module
import os
fname2 = "D:\X250\Python_Scripts\Search_File_for_Keyword_and_Print_Line\Results.txt"

# String to search
search_path = input("Enter directory path to search : ")
file_type = input("File Type : ")
search_str = input("Enter the search string : ")

#**Create Output File**
fw = open(fname2, 'w')

# Append a directory separator if not already present
if not (search_path.endswith("/") or search_path.endswith("\\") ): 
        search_path = search_path + "/"
                                                          
# If path does not exist, set search path to current directory
if not os.path.exists(search_path):
        search_path ="."

# Repeat for each file in the directory  
for fname in os.listdir(path=search_path):

   # Apply file type filter   
   if fname.endswith(file_type):

        # Open file for reading
        fo = open(search_path + fname)

        # Read the first line from the file
        line = fo.readline()

        # Initialize counter for line number
        line_no = 1

        # Loop until EOF
        while line != '' :
                # Search for string in line
                index = line.find(search_str)
                if ( index != -1) :
                    print(fname, "[", line_no, ",", index, "] ", line, sep="")
                    #Write Output File
                    fw.write(fname + " " + str(line_no) + " " + str(index)+"  ")
                    fw.write(line)

               

                # Read next line
                line = fo.readline()  

                # Increment line counter
                line_no += 1

                

        # Close the files
        fo.close()
```